# iOS notification push with a parse server hosted on heroku

Tags: ios, heroku, parse-platform, push-notification

I don't find an answer to my question: how can I send push Notification to ios devices from my parse-server hosted in heroku?
Thanks.

Comment: use cloud code.

Comment: what? who can I do this?